# URGENT - Office Laptop - Bluetooth Headset Installed Not Connecting

Tags: bluetooth, administrator

recently bought an Iball base09 bluetooth headset. which i am trying since 3days to install on my office laptop which is blocked with ADMIN PASSWORD all over.

IT guy from office installed all the drivers needed, but the audio device not showing up. the IT guy to gave up, and i am helpless since i cannot install any exe file.

can anyone please help urgently regarding this? 
its windows 7 and Hp 8440p Laptop.

P.S headset works fine on personal laptop.

Comment: What is so **urgent** that you can not use some wired headphones until your IT person has time to resolve it? Also if you really want help, some more information would be nice. Why did your IT guy give up, what was tried? Which bluetooth stack was installed (not a bluetooth stack if different from the bluetooth drivers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to go through your IT department to get this working. If the laptop is truly locked down then you will not be able to get the drivers/software properly loaded on to the machine even if you attempt a workaround method.

If this sort of support is covered in your companies' Service Level Agreement (SLA) and the IT department is unwilling to pursue it further, then you will be able to escalate the problem to a focal point or a manager.

If this is a personal request that is outside the SLA or a matter of convenience, you may be out of luck.

Comment: well guys thanks for the reply, the IT finally installed the device, now showing in audio device too. the problem now is its not gtting connected. :( dont know whats the issue now.can anyone please help??